# mongoose duplicate key error on insertMany

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to setup my test db, inserting multiples role items

```
...
  // ADD 3 roles in first group
  const roleA1 = { _groupId: groups[0]._id, name: 'admin', description: 'can RW group, user', users: [], permissions: permissions1 };
  const roleA2 = { _groupId: groups[0]._id, name: 'manager', description: 'can R group, can RW user', users: [], permissions: permissions2 };
  const roleA3 = { _groupId: groups[0]._id, name: 'employee', description: 'can R group, can read user', users: [], permissions: permissions3 };
  // ADD 2 roles in second group
  const roleB2 = { _groupId: groups[1]._id, name: 'manager', description: 'can R group, can RW user', users: [], permissions: permissions2 };
  const roleB3 = { _groupId: groups[1]._id, name: 'employee', description: 'can R group, can read user', users: [], permissions: permissions3 };
  // ADD 1 role in third group
  const roleC3 = { _groupId: groups[2]._id, name: 'employee', description: 'can R group, can read user', users: [], permissions: permissions3 };
  // ADD 1 role wo any group
  const role4 = { name: 'visitor', description: 'no permissions', users: [], permissions: [] };

  return Role.insertMany([roleA1, roleA2, roleA3, roleB2, roleB3, roleC3, role4 ])
    .then((insertedRoles) => {
      console.log('Successfully created test roles in groups');
      return insertedRoles;
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log('Error inserting many: %j', e);
      return e;
  });
```

I get a duplicated key on the roleB2. ( name 'manager') ... but the name field IS NOT define as unique in the Role model

```
  /**
   * Role Schema
   */
  const RoleSchema = new Schema({
    _groupId: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Group'},
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, trim: true, },
    users: [{ type: ObjectId }, { _id: false }],
    permissions: [PermissionSchema]
  });
```

there is no isNew tag to be set .. ?? what's wrong ?

thanks for your feedback

UPDATE

strange output of mongoose debug ... roles.count duplicated ... ???

```
groups[0]._id:  5954ee4d3b4027368ba66855
groups[0]._id:  5954ee4d3b4027368ba66856
groups[0]._id:  5954ee4d3b4027368ba66857
Mongoose: roles.count({ '$and': [ { _groupId: ObjectId("5954ee4d3b4027368ba66855") }, { name: 'admin' } ] }, {})
Mongoose: roles.count({ '$and': [ { _groupId: ObjectId("5954ee4d3b4027368ba66855") }, { name: 'admin' } ] }, {})
Mongoose: roles.count({ '$and': [ { _groupId: ObjectId("5954ee4d3b4027368ba66855") }, { name: 'manager' } ] }, {})
Mongoose: roles.count({ '$and': [ { _groupId: ObjectId("5954ee4d3b4027368ba66855") }, { name: 'manager' } ] }, {})
Mongoose: roles.count({ '$and': [ { _groupId: ObjectId("5954ee4d3b4027368ba66855") }, { name: 'employee' } ] }, {})
Mongoose: roles.count({ '$and': [ { _groupId: ObjectId("5954ee4d3b4027368ba66855") }, { name: 'employee' } ] }, {})
Mongoose: roles.count({ '$and': [ { _groupId: ObjectId("5954ee4d3b4027368ba66856") }, { name: 'manager' } ] }, {})
Mongoose: roles.count({ '$and': [ { _groupId: ObjectId("5954ee4d3b4027368ba66856") }, { name: 'manager' } ] }, {})
Mongoose: roles.count({ '$and': [ { _groupId: ObjectId("5954ee4d3b4027368ba66856") }, { name: 'employee' } ] }, {})
Mongoose: roles.count({ '$and': [ { _groupId: ObjectId("5954ee4d3b4027368ba66856") }, { name: 'employee' } ] }, {})
Mongoose: roles.count({ '$and': [ { _groupId: ObjectId("5954ee4d3b4027368ba66857") }, { name: 'employee' } ] }, {})
Mongoose: roles.count({ '$and': [ { _groupId: ObjectId("5954ee4d3b4027368ba66857") }, { name: 'employee' } ] }, {})
Mongoose: roles.count({ '$and': [ { _groupId: null }, { name: 'visitor' } ] }, {})
```

Comment: I did encounter something very similar to this a while ago can you remove this line `const roleB2 = { _groupId: groups[1]._id, name: 'manager', description: 'can R group, can RW user', users: [], permissions: permissions2 };` and see if you get a duplicate key on `roleB3` please

Comment: yes, I get a duplicated key on B3 in this case ...

Comment: So If you're creating multiple unique indices and then trying to save duplicate entries to the db where the only difference is the _id, it's going to fail

Comment: I understand, but in my case, there is a difference :  the _groupId fields is different...that's why I understand the error...

Comment: by any chance you have multiple models using the same collection? for example if you have "role model" and "roles model" mongoose will use the collection name(roles) for both. you need to explicitly set the model if this is the case

Comment: thanks for your help... I only have one roles collection BUT you put me on the way... I checked the db status and discovered that the roles collection was not dropped correctly in the before() hook... clearing manually the db made it... running again and it's solved... roles are added correctly into the db...

Comment: glad was able to help! happy coding